# How to map integer database type(s) to java boolean?

Tags: mapping, jdo, datanucleus

I'm already applying that and it works as if the integer value from the database is `0`, the java boolean variable becomes false and vice versa. But I'm wondering if it's possible to have it the other way around to map `0` for `true` and `1` for `false`.

Which got me thinking, i've earlier mapped java `enum`s to integers which is pretty well explained in the documentations and I'm wondering if Datanucleus is flexible enough to map any database type to any java type when either persisting the value or loading it. For example, to map database database below a specified value to java boolean `false` and exceeding that value to java boolean `true`. Or mapping strings to integers (string length may be).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps you just use standard JDO metadata and define the "jdbc-type" and see what happens. I wouldn't have thought its feasible to support every possible combination (and indeed many of them would be just plain daft).

Comment: I don't need to use `jdbc-type` to enable `integer` to `boolean` mapping. I'm just hoping to inverse\control that mapping.

Comment: JDO spec p 224 defines the *default* mappings. If you aren't using a default then yes you do have to specify jdbc-type.

Comment: You mean that if I'm mapping boolean java variables to mysql integers, I **have** to specify the `jdbc-type` ? Because that's not the case. I'm actually doing that without specifying the `jdbc-type`. I'm mapping java boolean variables to `INT(11)` mysql types. The mapped mysql integer columns values could only be `1` or `0` (Controlled by the application)

Comment: I mean that if you're using *default* database type (as per the JDO spec) then you don't need to specify jdbc-type, and if you're not then you have to specify jdbc-type